# Trying to upload an image to, and then show from, a database. Getting a fatal error

Tags: php, mysql

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\FinalProject\upload-profilePic.php:22 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:...

My Code:

Upload Image

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
if (file_exists($_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'])) {
    // get temp name and file name
    $tmpName = $_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['upload_file']['name'];
    $type = $_FILES['upload_file']['type'];

    $handler = fopen($tmpName, 'r'); // opens image file stream
    $data = fread($handler, filesize($tmpName)); // read byte data
    fclose($handler); // close image file stream

    $stmt = $con->prepare('insert into images (image_type,
        filename, image_data) values(?, ?, ?)');
    $stmt->bind_param('sss', $type, $fileName, $data);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if (!$result) {
        echo $con->error;
    }
  }
}

$result = $con->query('select * from images');
if ($result) {
    foreach ($result as $img) {
        $name = $img['filename'];
        $id = $img['image_id'];
        $url = "get-profilePic.php?id=$id";
        echo "<h3>$name</h3>";
        echo "<img src=\"$url\" alt=\"$name\" />\n\n";
    }
}
?>
```

Get Image

```
<?php

$imageId = $_GET['id'];
$result = $con->query("select * from images
where image_id = $imageId");

if ($result) { 
    $image = $result->fetch_object();
    $type = $image->image_type;
    $data = $image->image_data;
    header('Content-Type: ' . $type);
    echo $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: What is `$con` and how is it being created?

Comment: You may try not to upload the image directly to you database. All you need to do is insert the link as reference to your database. Then you can later call that link to get the image and use it wherever on your site. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: @IanKemp $con is my connection to the database. It is defined. I changed a column name and did not update it. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By considering your scenario, the problem lies in:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('insert into images (image_type, filename, image_data) values(?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $type, $fileName, $data);
```

The [prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) method can return false and there is a need to check for that as for why it returns false, perhaps the table name or column names (in SELECT or WHERE clause) are not correct? Mainly some error in your query.

Also, try using something like [$stmt ->error_list](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error-list.php) to check for the errors that occurred parsing the SQL.

Comment: thank you so much for your help! Ugh, I feel dumb. I changed one of my column names and did not update everything.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message says that `bind_param` is running on a `boolean`. This is generally caused by `$stmt` to be `false`, because `$con->prepare()` failed:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('insert into images (image_type,
    filename, image_data) values(?, ?, ?)');
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $type, $fileName, $data);
```

I can see that `$con` is not defined in your code. Can you verify it exists prior to these two lines of code?

```
var_dump($con);
```

Comment: $con is my connection to the database. It is defined. I changed the name of a column and did not update it.